# Oldest code in a typical Linux distro

Tags: linux, unix

Just out of curiosity: What's the oldest code/package in a typical linux distro? Emacs? GCC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sun RPC is pretty old, and it's in the C library:
[`http://blogs.oracle.com/webmink/entry/old_code_and_old_licenses`](http://blogs.oracle.com/webmink/entry/old_code_and_old_licenses)

Comment: link is dead - *Welcome to Oracle Blogs. The content that you're looking is no longer on this page.*

Comment: archive.org link here http://web.archive.org/web/20110812054324/https://blogs.oracle.com/webmink/entry/old_code_and_old_licenses

Answer (score 1):

In user space, there's a lot of code in coreutils that was written by RMS, which has not changed much since. The GNU project started out with lots of people writing free replacements to the UNIX core utilities (i.e. ls, cp, rm, etc), before the use of a window manager was even contemplated.

If you grab the source to the package, you'll find a lot of it.

Answer (score 1):

CC the compiler.

With its built in back door for building the login command.

Comment: Most Linux distros come with gcc, not the old cc, and I doubt that it has the (alleged!) back door.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Probably true. The back door was really only a straw man idea presented at the [ACM about trust](http://cm.bell-labs.com/who/ken/trust.html). But its a nice legend.

Answer (score 1):

I would say Paul Vixie Cron and the SYS V utilities (init) are some of the oldest stand-alone packages.  They are at long last replaced by upstart and other dependency- and event-based schemes.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this will be gcc as it was one of the first products from GNU and existed long before linux came.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would also be the gcc (GNU C Compiler).

Still in daily use, too.   As well as Emacs (no VI flaming necessary, thanks).

Answer (score 0):

So far as I know, the BSD fstab.h is the oldest code on a typical system; it is copyrighted 1980.